# Maven says it cannot find something in the "reactor"

Tags: maven

I have a maven project and I'm using this `--projects` command from the root of the project to run several pom files.

```
mvn clean install --projects proj1, then-proj2
```

The `proj1` and `then proj2` are the *artifact ids* of the projects I want to run. That is, I go to the `pom.xml` for each project and use the "artifact id" there.

Both proj1 & then-proj2 are themeslves sub modules of projects in the main pom file.

Say `proj1` is in A, and `then-proj2` is in B, and both A & B are in the main pom file.

When I run this, maven tells me: "could not find the selected project in the reactor: proj1".

This is really frustrating - why not tell me what **all** the projects in the reactor are? Anyway, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076358/1680793

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you only use the artifactId's of the given project you have to define that correctly on command line:

help output of Maven (`mvn --help`)

> Comma-delimited list of specified reactor projects to build  of all
>   projects. A project can be specified by [groupId]:artifactId or by its
>   relative path

This means in your case you have to define:

```
mvn clean install --projects :proj1,:then-proj2
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
mvn clean install -pl A/proj1, B/then-proj2
```

check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076358/1680793

Another thing is to make sure that you have listed your child projects inside the

```
<modules>
  <module>
```

sections of the corresponding parent multimodule projects.

For example in the below project structure:

- main

  - A

    - proj1

      - proj1A
  - B

    - then-proj2

Let's say you are trying to build proj1A. When you try

```
mvn package -pl A/proj1/proj1A
```

from the main's pom directory you will still have this same reactor error if you don't have:

- "A" as a module in "main", or
- "proj1" as a module in "A", or
- "proj1A" as a module in "proj1"

Comment: The key here is that -pl doesn't care about the artifact id in your submodule's pom.xml. Instead you need to look at that <module> tags on the parent's poms to build a path. In my limited experience the submodule names seem to line up the directory structure. @honor Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If your modules are distinguished based on profiles then make sure to consider profiles too. Eg:

```
mvn -P profile1 -pl relative/path/to/project1 clean install
```

For this kind of setting, the pom would be:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>project1</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <modules>
            <module>project2</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Not mentioning profile would also give the `Not Found in reactor`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me, run the below command from the root directory.

```
mvn clean install --projects :projA, :projB -am
```

assuming that *projB* is dependent on *projA*

> -am
>
> If project list is specified, also
>           build projects required by the
>           list

Answer (score 1):

The command used by you :

```
mvn clean install --projects 'submodule1','submodule2`
```

works on the sub-modules `submodule1` and `submodule2` specified in the `pom.xml` of the module where you're executing this command.

The guide to [Working with Multiple modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) shall help you understand the reactor and its sorting order. A general structure of the module for such use case would look like:

```
<groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
<artifactId>mainmodule</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.2.3</version>

<modules>
    <module>submodule1</module>
    <module>submodule2</module>
    ... others
</modules>
... other tags
```

Comment: all the terms maven uses are - to me - confusing. What xml element is the "sub module" name?

Comment: @bharal Have updated the answer, you can get to know more about it when you look at the `pom.xml` at the directory where you're executing this command.